# Summation - Gnuplot expression

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to use the summation expression in Gnuplot but it is not working properly. I have the following data structure with many number of rows:

> t   x1   y1   z1   x2   y2   z2   x3   y3   z3 ... x98  y98 z98

I would like to plot the following equation:

> u = (sqrt(sum(x)**2 + sum(y)**2 + sum(z)**2))/98

98 is the number of points (x,y,z).

What I have until now is how to plot the average of columns x1, x2, x3.. as following:

```
plot 'data file' u 1:((sum[i=0:ColCount-1] column(i*ColStep+ColStart))/ColCount) w lines ls 4 notitle

Where ColCount = 98, ColStep = 3 and ColStart=2.
```

But I have been trying to plot the equation, but it is not working. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: There may be additional problems, but to start with I think your expression for the column number is off by one (x1 is in column 1, not column 0).  So the first change to try is `plot ... using 1:((sum[i=0:ColCount-1] column( 1 + (i*ColStep+ColStart))/ColCount)) ...

Comment: Hi Ethan, thank you very much for your reply. I have checked the expression for the column number and it seems to be fine to me:
for i=0 --> 0*3+2 = 2 #here is x1
for i=1 --> 1*3 +2 = 5 #here is x2
for i=2 --> 2*3 +2=8 #here is x3
Then my point here is that the sum is happening for all x columns, since x1 begins at column number 2. 
Please let me know if I am wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: what does "not working" mean? Do you get an error message, do get a wrong graph...? For me, sum of x1 would mean: sum all values in the x1 column. But what you are currently calculating and plotting is the average of columns x1,x2,x3,...x98 versus t. It's not yet clear to me what you actually want.

Comment: @theozh, that is right. I did not describe the problem very well. What the current code does is to calculate and to plot the average of columns x1, x3, x3.. versus t. I have already edited my post. I'll answer the rest on your answer below to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the following script does:
It takes the square root of the sum of `(x1+x2+x3)**2` and `(y1+y2+y3)**2` and `(z1+z2+z3)**2`. This you can adapt to your column numbers.
But I'm still not sure whether this is what you want. Please clarify.

**Code:**

```
### summing up columns
reset session

$Data <<EOD
#t   x1   y1   z1   x2   y2   z2   x3   y3   z3
 1 1.11 1.21 1.31 2.11 2.21 2.31 3.11 3.21 3.31
 2 1.12 1.22 1.32 2.12 2.22 2.32 3.12 3.22 3.32
 3 1.13 1.23 1.33 2.13 2.23 2.33 3.13 3.23 3.33
 4 1.14 1.24 1.34 2.14 2.24 2.34 3.14 3.24 3.34
 5 1.15 1.25 1.35 2.15 2.25 2.35 3.15 3.25 3.35
 6 1.16 1.26 1.36 2.16 2.26 2.36 3.16 3.26 3.36
 7 1.17 1.27 1.37 2.17 2.27 2.37 3.17 3.27 3.37
 8 1.18 1.28 1.38 2.18 2.28 2.38 3.18 3.28 3.38
 9 1.19 1.29 1.39 2.19 2.29 2.39 3.19 3.29 3.39
EOD

ColStep = 3
ColCount = 3

mySum(ColStart) = sum[i=0:ColCount-1] column(i*ColStep+ColStart)

plot $Data u 1:(sqrt(mySum(2)**2 + mySum(3)**2 + mySum(4)**2)) w lp pt 7 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: thank you for helping me again. I really appreciate your help. 
Since my previous post was not so clear, the script above does almost everything that I would like. What I want is also to get the average of the columns. Hence, I just divided by ColCount as follows: mySum(ColStart) = ((sum[i=0:ColCount-1] column(i*ColStep+ColStart))/ColCount). The script is working perfectly. Thank you